# where clause evaluated by if

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5

I have a linq query that returns a schedule for a doctor in a specific date, that works ok:

```
var scheduledList = db_hms.Scheduled
    .Include("Natural_Person")
    .Include("Type_Schedule")
    .Where(s => s.id_medical_doctor == idMedic && s.date_time >= date && s.date_time <= EndDate).OrderBy(s => s.date_time).ToList();
```

but now, i have 2 extra fields i need to filter, so i need a way to evaluate if applay the filter or not, i was thinking in remove rhe `orderby` and the `toList()`and do somthing like:

```
if (idTipoConsulta != -1)
{
    scheduledList.Where(m => m.id_ps_schedule == idTipoConsulta);
}

if (idEspecialidad != -1)
{
    scheduledList.Where(m => m.id_specialty == idTipoConsulta);
}      

return scheduledList.OrderBy(s => s.date_time).ToList();
```

but it does not seem to work.

Comment: "it does not seem to work" is never enough information. In this case I happen to have been able to diagnose the issue, but please bear in mind the list at http://tinyurl.com/so-list when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Where` doesn't affect the object you call it on - it *returns* a new query with the filter applied. So you want to use the return value appropriately. For example:

```
if (idTipoConsulta != -1)
{
    scheduledList = scheduledList.Where(m => m.id_ps_schedule == idTipoConsulta);
}
// etc
```